# error_get_last() and custom error handler

Tags: php, error-handling

[`odbc_errormsg`](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php) 
does not report error messages from [`odbc_execute`](http://php.net/odbc_execute) the way it's supposed to. It merely throws a warning. So I've been forced to write a hack to parse the error message via [`error_get_last`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php).

I'm using [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and `error_get_last` returns `NULL` unless I either:

1. disable my error handler,
2. or make it return `FALSE`.

I'd suppose this is due to PHP's builtin error handler taking care of storing the error details somewhere so they can be retrieved later.

**Is there a way to emulate such behaviour in my custom error handler so `error_get_last()` can be used normally?**

*Please note I already know several ways to retrieve error info at any time. My question is how to make `error_get_last` usable.*

---

**Update:** I think I'd better post some code.

PHP has `error_get_last()`, which allows to do this:

```
@fopen('xxx');
var_dump( error_get_last() );
```

... and get this:

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["message"]=>
  string(46) "fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given"
  ["file"]=>
  string(69) "C:\Documents and Settings\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\Mis documentos\tmp\test.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

This breaks if you replace the builtin error handler:

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $ignore = ($errno & error_reporting()) == 0;
    if(!$ignore){
        echo "[Error happened: $errstr]\n";
    }
    return TRUE;
}
set_error_handler('custom_error_handler');

@fopen('xxx');
var_dump( error_get_last() ); // NULL
```

If you keep both error handlers...

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $ignore = ($errno & error_reporting()) == 0;
    if(!$ignore){
        echo "[Error happened: $errstr]\n";
    }
    return FALSE;
}
set_error_handler('custom_error_handler');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo $foo;
```

... you get side effects:

```
[Error happened: Undefined variable: foo]

Notice: Undefined variable: foo in C:\Documents and Settings\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\Mis documentos\tmp\test.php on line 15

Call Stack:
    0.0004     329720   1. {main}() C:\Documents and Settings\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\Mis documentos\tmp\test.php:0
```

... instead of just:

```
[Error happened: Undefined variable: foo]
```

I want to my custom error handler to interface properly with `error_get_last`. I want `error_get_last` to work fine.

Comment: Would you accept using a different (user-defined) function? Because if you would, you could just store the last error in a global var, and have a function that just does `return $GLOBALS['varname'];`

Comment: Is returning `false` not acceptable? If so, why?

Comment: Also, have you tried assigning a value to [`$php_errormsg`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php)? I have no idea if this would achieve (or even affect) anything, but it might be worth a try...

Comment: @Jon - Because it executes both error handlers: first mine, then PHP's. Mine is a replacement, not a complement.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I understand that. My question could be also phrased as "what problem does PHP's error handler cause if you let it execute?".

Comment: @DaveRandom - I know there're many ways to replace `error_get_last()`. I just want to write a custom error handler that doesn't break other functionality. /// Setting `$php_errormsg` doesn't prevent `error_get_last()` from returning NULL (just tested it).

Comment: @Jon - The most obvious is a second error message on screen.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I 'm asking because I am considering possible hacks. Did you try simply reimplementing the functionality of `error_get_last` from within your own handler (i.e. saving to some variable and fetching it later)? At first sight it seems to be the cleanest possible solution.

Comment: @Jon - Unlike JavaScript, PHP does not allow to redefine functions. I can write my own function but it cannot call it `error_get_last()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I imagine the name of the function to call is not part of your requirements, right?

Answer (score 6):

Right, this is a bizarre solution, but I *think* it will suit your purposes.

After a bit of playing around, I have discovered that this:

```
function my_error_handler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile = '', $errline = 0, $errcontext = array()) {

  // Handle the error here

  @trigger_error($errstr);
  return TRUE;

}

// Just to make sure PHP is not outputting anything
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

set_error_handler('my_error_handler');

// An E_USR error...
trigger_error('Some error');
var_dump(error_get_last());

// ...and a native one
$key = count();
var_dump(error_get_last());
```

Results in this:

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(1024)
  ["message"]=>
  string(10) "Some error"
  ["file"]=>
  string(69) "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(7)
}
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(1024)
  ["message"]=>
  string(45) "count() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given"
  ["file"]=>
  string(69) "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Calling `@trigger_error()` from within your error handler, and not returning `FALSE`, causes `error_get_last()` to return something other than `NULL`, but because the error is suppressed with `@`, PHP doesn't output anything. It seems that in the interests of avoiding an infinite recursion, calling `trigger_error()` from within the registered error handler function does not call the error handler - which works to our advantage here.

Obviously, the error code has been modified, but you could convert it to the relevant `E_USR_*` code if you need - but I suspect what you really want is the string value, which this method will allow you get. You have, unfortunately, also lost the line number and file information - although you could possibly get this back by doing something involving a stack trace inside the error handler, or at the very least including it in the string from the arguments passed.

This is a horrible, horrible, horrible hack - but since there is no officially sanctioned way to do this, a hack is essentially what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your custom error handler to return false, just when the error is ignored (@-operator used).

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $ignore = ($errno & error_reporting()) == 0;
    if ($ignore) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    echo "[Error happened: $errstr]\n";
    return TRUE;
}
```